# Rails - Email sign-up confirmation - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, confirmation-email

I want an email to be sent when a user registers. This email should contain a link **that changes the account to a full user**. I want this email link to be a token for security.

- email_token  is a random generated token per user
- email_activation_token  is a boolean saying if the user completed registration or not

**Currently**: I get the email to send but when I click the link I get this error.

### NoMethodError in UsersController#accept_invitation

```
undefined method `email_activation_token=' for nil:NilClass
```

**Link Sent** `http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation.tLPOjM3hdA13rEv5FNhsOQ`

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end

  def accept_invitation
      @user = User.find_by_email_token(params[:email_token])
      @user.email_activation_token = true
      @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
  end
  end
end
```

**registration_confirmation.html.haml**

```
Confirm your email address please!

= accept_invitation_users_url(@user.email_token)
```

**user.rb model**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

      attr_accessor :password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
      before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
      before_create { generate_token(:email_token) }

      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$/
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :password, :on => :create, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the URL which you are sending out in your email

```
http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation.tLPOjM3hdA13rEv5FNhsOQ
```

In the above link, there are no params generated and thus when the first line of the accept_invitation action runs, then @user is set to nil because there are no params[:email_token].

According to me, you should set your link something like

**registration_confirmation.html.haml**

```
Confirm your email address please!

= accept_invitation_users_url(:email_token => @user.email_token)
```

in your mailer view

Comment: But that's an individual token random generated per user for security purposes. It would defeat the purpose if I use the same token for each account.

Comment: He's right - I assume he means `= accept_invitation_users_url(email_token: @user.email_token)`. This would give you `http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation?email_token=tLPOjM3hdA13rEv5FNhsOQ` and mean that `params[:email_token]` would be defined.